# how to load class at runtime in c# vsix project

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, vsix, .net-framework-version

I can able to create the class for the Json. But how to load the generated class at runtime for deserialization operation in vsix project.

//json for generating class

[
{
"Id": 1,
"Name": "Alpha",
"Gender": "Female",
"KnownLanguages": [ "c#", "Javascript" ]
},
{
"Id": 2,
"Name": "Alexa",
"Gender": "Female",
"KnownLanguages": [ "Python", "Java" ]
},
{
"Id": 3,
"Name": "Mark ",
"Gender": "Male",
"KnownLanguages": [ "c", "Javascript" ]
}
]

//creating class dynamically with respect to the json
//schemaFile consist of json data

```
var classGenerator = new CSharpGenerator(schemaFile, new CSharpGeneratorSettings { ClassStyle = CSharpClassStyle.Poco, Namespace = "JsonModifier" });
```

//generate student class file

```
var codeFile = classGenerator.GenerateFile();
```

//writes the generated student class in the Student.cs file

```
 File.WriteAllText("JsonModifier\\Model\\Student.cs", codeFile);
```

//selectedText have the data for deserializing

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(selectedText);
```

In this above deserialization i hardcoded the class name, but i need to load the class dynamically. How to do it?

Comment: If you read the documentation, [JsonConvert class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) does indeed contain methods for deserializing an object based on a passed in Type. So no, a specific type would not have to be hardcoded in, it can certainly be deserialized using passed in information.

Comment: How do you know what type you want to deserialize to? You seem to know the class name when writing the filename (Student.cs) so you could use reflection to load that class. Of course, you'll have to get it to compile and reload the assembly dynamically since the class you've created didn't exist when the assembly was first created. That's probably not trivial.